# c# override streamreader but can I close and reopen it?

Tags: c#, cvs, streamreader

I'm merging some of my cvs reading code into a single class, and I'm thinking of just making it override streamreader.  However, I want to keep the class private values I added (delimiter, recordcount, etc) and be able to close and reopen the file.

The reason I need to be able to is to do a quick pass to determine various things such as the delimiter, whether there are embedded line breaks in the data, actual record count, field count, etc.

Obviously I can't use using (streamreader sr = new streamreadder(filename)) because that will destroy the object at the end but can I close the file and reopen it?  Can I do cvsstreamclass sr = new cvsstreamclass(filename), and then sr.close() and sr.open()?  I understand that streamreader seek has problems so I probably shouldn't just use that.

Or am I going about this all wrong and should I just pass in the streamreader object to a class that handles the parsing and whatnot??

btw, I'm not looking at switching to an opensource cvs class or other library. I've already got a lot of this code written, and it works. No need to suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV parser *is not* a `StreamReader`. The two are not related and there should not be an inheritance relationship.

Your `CsvReader` class should have a `StreamReader` member. You can the set and manipulate that member however you like. For example, you can close the existing reader and create a new one at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you actually store the `StreamReader` in your reader class. There is no point in subclassing `StreamReader` unless you're going to expose it to some other code in the form of a `StreamReader`. I would do something like this:

```
public class CSVReader
{
    private StreamReader reader;
    private string fileName;

    //Your other properties and fields here

    public CSVSReader(string filename)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        InitReader();
    }

    public void CloseFile()
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
        }
    }

    public void OpenFile()
    {
        CloseFile();
        reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
    }

    //Your other methods here
}
```

Obviously, I'm not using any try-catch blocks for opening the file, but that's just for the sake of readability.

You could also inherit from `IDisposable`, making your class usable inside a `using ()` block.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps a great deal.

Comment: If you feel this is the solution please consider marking it as answered :)

Comment: Done.  I never noticed that checkmark before.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jim wrong one, I think :P maybe usr's one was better suited for you :)